# Check the pressed key and and add it to String

Tags: c#, string, console

I am coding and i have a problem with c#. I have following code:

```
    if (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString() == "l") // Reading single key in console
            goto load; 
// If not, continue

// Here, if I didn't press "l", I have to press the key once more, because at first, it checked it in if statement above so it is reding this into the string on the second time. So just want that if I didn't press "l" Automatically add that key to string below
            string read = Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is that if I don't want to press "l" the first letter, I must press something else 2 times. (Because that first press is checking Console.ReadKey().)
So how can i make that if I press different key than "l" it will automatically write it to Console.ReadLine which is below? Thanks

Comment: If you have `goto` in your code you're about to have a lot more problems

Comment: @UnholySheep already told him/her, but ....

Comment: avoid using `goto` statement, you can use an `if` instead

Comment: I deleted that label and goto and that is the same problem here.

Comment: If you deleted it, please update your code.

Comment: Ok, it is updated

Comment: word of advice, `DON'T use GOTO Statements`\

Comment: Don't pass `true` to readkey if you want the character to show on the screen. That parameter specifies if you want to *intercept* the character: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to capture the first character into a variable, so you can save it for later in case it's not the one you're looking for. Also, note that we don't pass `true` to the `ReadKey()` method if we want the output to show on the console window.

If the input is not the one you were looking for, then you can save the result of `Console.ReadLine()` into another variable, and add the original character to the beginning of it:

```
// First capture the character into a variable, so we can save it for later
var firstChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();

if (firstChar == "l")
{
    // Do something here, or call another method,
    // But don't GOTO anywhere.
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed 'l'");
}
else
{
    // If they didn't press 'L', then we take the saved character and
    // Add it to the beginning of the rest of the user input:
    var restOfInput = firstChar + Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"You entered the text: {restOfInput}");
}
```